# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when running project in netbeans 8 with jdk 7

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

This question seems to be a duplicate but it's not!
I run ubuntu from a live pendrive only and wanted to test a netbeans project for linux.
I have installed oracle's jdk 7u67, netbeans 8. When I tried to run the project,system freezes. now i'll have to  install those softwares again after reboot.

I have read from other's posts that using openjdk/downgrading netbeans to 7.1 won't solve my problem on ubuntu 14.04. what are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Oracle Java 8 for Ubuntu. From the terminal run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

The installation also includes JRE8 and the Java browser plugin. The installer requires you to accept the Oracle license before the installation begins.

For more information visit [Install Oracle Java 8 in Ubuntu via PPA repository (JDK8)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

Comment: downloading jdk is in progress.can i take backup of "jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz" so that i don't have to download it again.(low speed connection)

Comment: It would be a good idea to make a backup of "jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz" after the download is finished.

Comment: but where does that store in ubuntu??

Comment: Check the file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz If it is small (~5000 bytes) then it contains text telling you to accept the Oracle license, and if so also search for jdk packages in `/var/cache` and `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Answer (score 3):

This is some sort of bug between the openjdk, gtk, and some assistive technologies libraries. If you are not using accessibility tools you can stop openjdk using them too as follows:

`sudo rm /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`

Alterantively, comment out the line that starts with "assistive_technologies".

See:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798131

Comment: You saved my day, thanks!